# Model value not being set in Xamarin in iOS Only

Tags: ios, asp.net, model, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a Xamarin App where I am facing an issue.

Case 1:

Mode: Debug

Error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Explanation:
No value is being set and passed to ViewModel, Controller.
Even I tried setting static values to variables and parameters.

```
LoginModel logtest = new LoginModel();
            logtest.Username = "Test@user.com"; //uName;
            logtest.Password = "2342534"; //pWord;
```

Tried solution:
In the beginning, I tried many different solutions nothing worked.

Then I create a new project and moved all the code to the new project, then it started working.

Case 2:

Mode: release

Now the same issue I am getting in release mode.
No value is being set and passed to ViewModels and Controller.

I have already tried moving code to a new project.

How can I resolve this? I am not sure is this a Visual studio issue or Xamarin issue or Apple.

I have tried updating Visual Studio enterprise 2019 and Xcode on Mac.

Deleted and recreated Provisioning Profiles and Signing Identities.

Code From LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
 private async void LoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            await ((LoginViewModel)BindingContext).Login();  
       }
    
    
    
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
         {
                 //App.Current.MainPage = new Navigation(new DashboardPage());
                 //load the login page               
    
                 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         ((LoginViewModel)BindingContext).IsLoading = false;
    
                         ((LoginViewModel)BindingContext).RememberMe = DeviceStorage.RememberMe;
                         if (DeviceStorage.RememberMe == true)
                         {
                             ((LoginViewModel)BindingContext).UserName = "Test@user.ca";  //Trying set static values here
                             ((LoginViewModel)BindingContext).Password = "password"; //Trying set static values here
                         }
                         //RememberMeToggle.Toggled += switcher_Toggled;
                         ((LoginViewModel)BindingContext).Load();
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                         //logger.Error(App.LogPrefix() + "Error opening Navigation Page: " + ex.Message);
                         Console.WriteLine(App.LogPrefix() + "Error opening Load(): " + ex.Message);
                     }
                 });
         }
```

Code from LoginViewModel.cs

```
 public async Task Login()
         {
             IsLoading = true;
             await TokenController.GetAuthorizationToken(UserName, Password);
         }
```

Code from TokenController.cs

```
public static async Task GetAuthorizationToken(string uName, string pWord)
         {
             bool tokenReturned = false;
             string tokenGetResponse = string.Empty;
    
              // Have tried setting them static values as well 
    
             LoginModel logtest = new LoginModel();
             logtest.Username = uName;
             logtest.Password = pWord;
             logtest.AppType = Constants.AppDetails.APP_CODE;
             logtest.SystemCode = Constants.AppDetails.SYSTEM_CODE;
             logtest.Push.PushSystem = PushAddressModel.PushSystemCode.FireBase;
             logtest.Push.Address = ((App)App.Current).PushNotificationToken;
             logtest.Push.AppCode = Constants.AppDetails.APP_CODE;
             string uri = URI.message_Chat_Endpoint;
             (tokenReturned, tokenGetResponse) = await ApiFunctions.Post(logtest, URI.token_Endpoint, false);
    
             if (tokenReturned)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     //deserialize the return object
                     TokenModel token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(tokenGetResponse);
                     ((App)App.Current).token = token;
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                     //logger.Error(App.LogPrefix() + "Error: " + ex.Message);
                 }
    
                 Console.WriteLine("Profile Token loaded: " + ((App)App.Current).token.access_token);
             }
             else
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Error: Error loading profile token ");
                 //logger.Error(App.LogPrefix() + "Error loading profile token");
             }
         }
```

Comment: There is no enough code here for us to be able to help you.  Please read [mcve]

Comment: Hi, @Jason Thank you for your response. I have updated the question please have a look.

Comment: Have you checked if RememberMe is set correctly?  That seems like the most likely cause

Comment: @Jason nope, that is not the issue. issue is Model is not being set. using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` this i was able to set value and able to pass `GetAuthorizationToken(string uName, string pWord)` but then i was not able to set model  ```LoginModel logtest = new LoginModel();
            logtest.Username = "Test@user.com"; //uName;
            logtest.Password = "2342534"; //pWord;
```

Comment: then i tried setting model in `LoginPage.xaml.cs` file and pass to `GetAuthorizationToken()` function. again model values were empty.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on my side?